# Issue with MySQL Compound Primary Key

Tags: mysql, optimization, compound-key

I am having an issue with a table the uses a compound primary key.
The key consists of a date followed by an bigint.

Selects on the table look to be scanning even when only selecting fields from the PK and using a where clause that contains both columns. For Example

```
SELECT mydate, myid from foo WHERE mydate >='2014-08-26' AND my_id = 1234;
```

Explain select shows using where and the number of rows considered is in the millions.

One oddity is the key_len which is shown as 7 which seems far too small.

My instinct says the key is broken but I may be missing something obvious.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Richard

Comment: MySQL 5.5 on percona cluster.

Comment: Please post result of `show create table foo;` and `explain select...`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query, the index you want is on `id, date`:

```
 create index idx_foo_myid_mydate on foo(my_id, mydate);
```

This is because the conditions in the `where` clause have an equality and inequality.  The equality conditions need to match the index from left to right, before the inequalities can be applied.

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) actually does a good job (in my opinion) in explaining composite indexes.

Your existing index will be used for the inequality on `mydate`.  However, all the index after the date in question will then be scanned to satisfy the condition on `my_id`.  With the right index, MySQL can just go to the right rows directly.

Comment: Thank you oh the joy of adding and index to 66M rows :)